# Android (9) Pie's native "Back Up" to google drive grayed out

Tags: backup, 9.0-pie, google-backup

Android Pie has a native manual back up to google drive. After I turned off the back up and turned it back on, the back up button is grayed out.

Since then I

1. Re-added my google account on my phone
2. Cleared Google Drive cache

as described [here](https://www.fonepaw.com/backup/google-backup-not-working-android.html), but to no effect.

Another person [solved](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/1520722?hl=en) the issue through the ADB debugger. I ask here because I would like to avoid installing ADB. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I can back up now. I have no idea why this is and what changed, but the button works.